# Changing namespace and schemaLocation attributes in WCF

Tags: wcf, wsdl, xml-namespaces

I developed a WCF service in C#. Our customer already has a client software written in Java. They say when they try to add our wcf service reference, they get an error. They think that the problem about namespaces.
I don't know much about namespaces or any other tag details in WCF.
They say wcf service's wsdl output has to be like the following:

```
<xsd:import id="base" namespace="http://helios.theircompanyName.com/im schemaLocation="http://wwwdev1.theirCompanyName.com:8000/HeliosIM/im?xsd=1"/>
```

But our service gives:

```
<xsd:import schemaLocation="http://myComputerName/MyWcfProjectFolder/MyWcfService.svc?xsd=xsd0" namespace="http://tempuri.org/"/>
```

As it can be seen, my service has no attribute like `id="base"` and `namespace`, `schemaLocation` attributes are different.
How can I change WCF to generate wsdl xml like they want?

Comment: Firstly, what binding are you using?

Comment: @hugh I use basicHttpBinding.

Comment: first problem:  you used WCF.  Second problem, you're using wsdl.  Solution: Stop using WSDL and WCF.  Start using REST and Web API and your life will be much, much simpler.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want to change the namespace of your service from tempuri.org (which is the WCF default) you need to change it in 4 places:

1. Service contract
2. Data contracts
3. Service implementation
4. BindingNamespace in endpoint config element

For example:

```
// Service Contract
[ServiceContract(Namespace="http://myNamespace")]
public interface IMyService
{}

// Data Contract
[DataContract(Namespace="http://myNamespace")]
public class MyType
{}

// Service implementation
[ServiceBehavior(Namespace="http://myNamespace")]
public class Service : IMyService
{}

<!-- In config -->
<endpoint address="http://whatever" 
          bindingNamespace="http://myNamespace"
          binding="basicHttpBinding" 
          contract="Something.IMyService" />
```

HOWEVER, I don't really understand why they are telling you this is necessary. As the provider of the service, it's up to you rather than them what namespace you provide. Whatever this value is set to they will likely have the same problems consuming the wsdl.

The same goes with the schemaLocation, again, it's not up to them where this location points to. Schemalocation is actually completely optiona when you're doing an import in xml schema, so if they're dependent on some value being in there then they're not xsd compliant.

I would guess they're having difficulties consuming your WSDL and do not quite understand what is wrong, so have chosen to blame your service. The service metadata exposed over the basicHttpBinding is the most interoperable of the entire WCF stack, and should be 100% consumable from java.

How are they trying to build their client? Is your service running somewhere they can see it?

Comment: I also think that they blame our service becuse they dont know about the error they receive in their application. Your summary about defining namespaces in wcf is so clear. thank you.