# What url is needed to consume WCF service

Tags: wcf

I have created a WCF service in Visual Studio 2010 and published it to a server running IIS 7.5.

It has one method - called returnNumber. This takes an int parameter called numberIn, multiplies it by 2 and returns the answer.

If I put

```
http://myserver/TestService/Service1.svc?wsdl
```

in a browser, it displays a page of XHTML.

What url should I use so that I can call my WCF service from a browser - passing a number in the QueryString so that the returnNumber method is called?

---

Further to responses below - Daniel - here is my code:

The web config:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
<system.web>
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
</system.web>
<system.serviceModel>
<behaviors>
<serviceBehaviors>
<behavior>
<!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
<serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
<!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true. Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
<serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
</behavior>
</serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
</system.serviceModel>
<system.webServer>
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

An IServicer1.cs file containing an interface:

```
namespace NumberTest
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IService1
    {
    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = false)]
    int returnNumber(int numberIn);
    }
}
```

And Service1.svc.cs

```
namespace NumberTest
{
    public class NumberService : IService1
    {
        public int returnNumber(int numberIn)
        {
        int returnValue = numberIn * 2;
        return returnValue;
    }
}
```

I have published the above to

```
http://myServer/TestService
```

and, if I add a reference to the WCF service from within a VS Web Application, the returnNumber method is exposed and works if I call it.

How do I allow people running web sites that are not asp.net (so they cannot add a service reference) to be able to call my returnNumber method and get a number back?

Comment: you should probably consider web api for this kind of functionality

Comment: When you say a 'web api' do you mean a soap web service?

Comment: No, I mean the ASP.net WebApi framework. Google is your friend...

Comment: Browsers communication in HTML, WCF is SOAP based. If you want it to be accessible from the browser a Web API is your best bet.
http://www.asp.net/web-api

For WCF the WCF Test Client is a good option (see Daniel's answer)

Comment: You can add this to your mozilla and call your rest service https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/restclient if you're using **REST service**. and the path you've metion in your `UriTemplate` your response will be shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To pass arguments to a service on the querystring you are unfortunately not using the correct technology stack.

WCF exposes web operations across a SOAP 1.2 (by default) endpoint, which means that the web server expects a SOAP request (that is a soap envelope wrapping the XML request payload) directed to the services URL.

What you want to do is hook up a pure HTTP web service, for which the correct Microsoft technology stack is [ASP.NET WebApi](http://www.asp.net/web-api).

Comment: ' ...  which means that the web server expects a SOAP request (that is a soap envelope wrapping the XML request payload) directed to the services URL ...'

Thank you. What would I need to tell someone who wants to call my WCF service from a jsp web site?

Comment: Tell them to consume the metadata from your service's metadata address (which is the service address with ?wsdl on the end). This metadata contains information about the operations and types exposed across your service boundary, and will enable the caller to construct a service "proxy" which will enable them to call your service methods as if they were in-process on their end. I'm not a Java dev but I think JabX will do this.

Comment: thanks for your help. I find the ?wsdl file is full of references to tempuri.org. Will this be a problem? Do I need to get rid of them?

Comment: Nope these are there because WSDL specification requires you to declare an xml namespace for the types you expose. It doesn't really matter what this value is. However if you want to control the namespace on your service check here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19054231/569662

Comment: Thanks again. One final question if I may - what is the difference between a ServiceContract and a DataContract? I see ServiceContract implements (correct terminology?) an Interface which the Class in Service1.svc.cs inherits from - whereas DataContract just contains a class with members. Each member is preceded by [DataMember]. What is [DataMember] doing? I have never noticed it before other class properties.

Comment: DataContract and DataMember are attributes that tells the WCF serializer that this type or field need to be serialized and exposed across the service boundary. You don't need to use it if you are only exposing simple types on your service.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the WCF Test Client (depending on the version of VS you are using), pop in the address for your WSDL, and use that to test your web serivce.

If you use the test client and a tool such as Fiddler, you could find out the URLs that are being used under the covers by looking for HTTP POSTs to your web service.

Comment: I'm using VS 2010. Where do you access the WCF Test Client?

Have I got hold of the wrong end of the stick completely? I thought WCF services were supposed to provide the ability to (for example) send data to someone else's server, and get an answer back. If they are not accessibly by sending parameters in a querystring - what is the point? (Other than other Windows users being able to add a Service reference - but what about people not using Windows and building asp.net apps?)

Comment: @MartinSmellworse Have a look in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE (for VS 2010, change to Visual Studio 10.0) for WcfTestClient.exe.

You've not got the wrong end of the stick with regard to the purpose of web services. You can't really test in a browser though - you need to be making POSTs with all but the simplest of web services (I can't say if yours expects a POST without seeing code and config) so the WCF Test Client is ideal for testing because it figures that out.

Comment: @MartinSmellworse Have a look at http://www.getpostman.com/ - useful for testing web services as long as you're comfortable crafting the requests.

Comment: But of a nuisance -  I'm being chased for something else at the moment (work eh!) ... I'll come back later today and post the code I'm using in my original question ... perhaps you could have a look later this afternoon? Thanks.

Comment: Will do my best to be around :D

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your second question, consuming your web service from a non-asp.net platform, you should only need to configure your service to provide the WSDL.

Non-.net platforms, aka Java, have tools, such as wsdl2java, that consume the WSDL and produce the necessary client code.

The tools and usage will vary depending on platform, but the following link should provide a valuable point of reference. http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/docs/userguide-creatingclients.html

Regards,